# How to get text value of specific columns in a table for each row?

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a simple HTML table that can contain 2-5 rows and 6 columns each. How can I get the value of 1 and 2 columns for each row? I would also like to display it in a output like this: `Column1 Column2, Column1 Column2, Column1 Column2` would be the output if it has 3 rows.

**EDIT:** Created a jsfiddle to describe what Im trying to do and also the sample code where I am at so far https://jsfiddle.net/y6eoc0b4/

Comment: Did you try anything ? Share your code please.

Comment: @MohamedAbbas I created a jsfiddle to describe what im trying to do https://jsfiddle.net/y6eoc0b4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
var rows = myTable.getElementsByTagName("tr");
console.log(rows);
var output = [];
for(var i = 0; i< rows.length; i++){

    var cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
  output.push(cells[0].innerText+" "+cells[1].innerText)
}
document.getElementsByClassName("output")[0].innerText = output;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/LyswLtf8/

Answer (score 1):

JSfiddle based on your comment [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ce6quh87/1/)

```js
//step first: select items like this
var fisrstTdArr = document.querySelectorAll(".location table tbody tr td:first-child");
var secondTdArr = document.querySelectorAll(".location table tbody tr td:nth-child(2)");

// or like this
var fisrstTdArr2 = document.querySelectorAll("#myId tbody tr td:first-child");
var secondTdArr2 = document.querySelectorAll("#myId tbody tr td:nth-child(2)");

// or even shorter if you have only one table on the page
var fisrstTdArr3 = document.querySelectorAll("td:first-child");
var secondTdArr3 = document.querySelectorAll("td:nth-child(2)");

for (var i = 0; i<fisrstTdArr.length; i++) { // than loop
  console.log ('select method 1, fisrts column: ' + fisrstTdArr[i].innerText); // and use
  console.log ('select method 1, second column: ' + secondTdArr[i].innerText);
  console.log ('select method 2, fisrts column: ' + fisrstTdArr2[i].innerText);
  console.log ('select method 2, second column: ' + secondTdArr2[i].innerText);
  console.log ('select method 3, fisrts column: ' + fisrstTdArr3[i].innerText);
  console.log ('select method 3, second column: ' + secondTdArr3[i].innerText);
}
```

```html
<div class='location'>
<table id="myId">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>else</td>
<td>here</td>
<td>else</td>
<td>here</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>c</td>
<td>d</td>
<td>else</td>
<td>here</td>
<td>else</td>
<td>here</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>e</td>
<td>f</td>
<td>else</td>
<td>here</td>
<td>else</td>
<td>here</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>else</td>
<td>here</td>
<td>else</td>
<td>here</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>else</td>
<td>here</td>
<td>else</td>
<td>here</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a fixable code that can work on a table with any number of columns and any number of rows.

```js
var table = document.querySelector('#my-table'),
  trs   = table.querySelectorAll('tr'),
    outputDiv = document.querySelector('#output') ,
    tds = [],
    i, j,
    output = ''; 
    
  for (i = 0; i < trs.length; i += 1) {
   tds = trs[i].querySelectorAll('td');
    output += "Row #" + (i + 1) + "<br>";
    for (j = 0; j < tds.length; j += 1) {
     output += tds[j].innerText + ' ';
    }
    output += '<br>-----------------<br>';
  }
  
  outputDiv.innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<table border=1 id="my-table">
  <tr>
    <td>Row1-Column1</td>
    <td>Row1-Column2</td>
    <td>Row1-Column3</td>
    <td>Row1-Column4</td>
    <td>Row1-Column5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row2-Column1</td>
    <td>Row2-Column2</td>
    <td>Row2-Column3</td>
    <td>Row2-Column4</td>
    <td>Row2-Column5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row3-Column1</td>
    <td>Row3-Column2</td>
    <td>Row3-Column3</td>
    <td>Row3-Column4</td>
    <td>Row3-Column5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<span style="font-weight: bold">Desired Output:</span> "Row1-Column1 Row1-Column2, Row2-Column1 Row2-Column2, Row3-Column1 Row3-Column2"
<br>
<br>
<span>Output:</span> <div id="output"></div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y6eoc0b4/2/)